# Find rare events in flowing window on timestamp

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, timestamp, window-functions

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE table
(
 "id" serial NOT NULL,
 "timestamp" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
 "count" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)
```

I am searching for "rare events". A rare event is a row that owns the following properties:

- Simple: `count = 1`
- Hard: All rows within a 10 minute timespan (before and after the current row's timestamp) have `count = 0` (except the given row, of course).

Example:

```
id   timestamp  count
0    08:00      0    
1    08:11      0    
2    08:15      2     <== not rare event (count!=1)   
3    08:19      0    
4    08:24      0    
5    08:25      0   
6    08:29      1     <== not rare event (see 8:35)
7    08:31      0    
8    08:35      1    
9    08:40      0    
10   08:46      1     <== rare event!  
10   08:48      0   
10   08:51      0   
10   08:55      0   
10   08:58      1     <== rare event!  
10   09:02      0   
10   09:09      1
```

Right now, I have the following PL/pgSQL-function:

```
SELECT curr.* 
    FROM gm_inductionloopdata curr
    WHERE curr.count = 1
    AND (
      SELECT SUM(count)
      FROM gm_inductionloopdata
      WHERE timestamp BETWEEN curr.timestamp + '10 minutes'::INTERVAL
      AND curr.timestamp - '10 minutes'::INTERVAL
    )<2
```

which is dead slow. :-(

Any suggestions on how to improve performance? I am working on > 1 mio rows here and might need to find those "rare events" on a regular basis.

Comment: Your query is wrong, there is no WHERE and the BETWEEN is flipped (should be `- '10 min...' AND ... + '10 min...')...

Comment: Also, have you tried an index on timestamp column to see if your current query works well?

Comment: Are there really seven rows with the same ID? Does "timestamp" really mean "time"? (In SQL databases, *timestamp* usually means date and time, not just time, which is a different data type altogether in PostgreSQL.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be faster, yet (improving the [1st solution of @Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18594361/939860)).

```
SELECT id, ts, ct
FROM  (
    SELECT id, ts, ct
        ,lag (ts, 1, '-infinity') OVER (ORDER BY ts) as prev_ts
        ,lead(ts, 1,  'infinity') OVER (ORDER BY ts) as next_ts
    FROM   tbl
    WHERE  ct <> 0
    ) sub
WHERE  ct = 1
AND    prev_ts < ts - interval '10 min'
AND    next_ts > ts + interval '10 min'
ORDER  BY ts;
```

- Handling of the corner cases of "no leading / lagging row" can be much simplified with the following two pieces of information:

  - Postgres knows the [special timestamp values `-infinity` and `infinity`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE).
  - [`lead()` and `lag()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) support default values.
- **Subqueries** are generally more efficient than CTEs (some exceptions apply), since CTEs introduce optimization barriers (by design and on purpose). If performance matters, use CTEs only when you *need* them.

Also:

- I use **proper column names** instead of `timestamp` and `count`, thereby removing the need to double-quote identifiers. Never use reserved words or basic type or function names as identifiers.
- None of this has anything to do with <strike>[plpgsql](/questions/tagged/plpgsql)</strike>, which is the default procedural language of Postgres.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/54327/1)

### Index

Since we are dealing with a **big table** (`> 1 mio rows`) and are only interested in "**rare** events" the important thing for performance is a [**partial index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) like the following:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_rare_idx ON tbl(ts) WHERE ct <> 0;
```

If you are on **Postgres 9.2 or later** and given some preconditions, make that a [**covering index** for index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans).

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_rare_covering_idx ON tbl(ts, ct, id)
WHERE ct <> 0;
```

- Order of columns is important. `ts` must come first, `ct` should come next. Other columns you need in the `SELECT` follow.
- Read the [page about index-only scans in the Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) for details!

Test with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) to see which query is faster and whether the index is used.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a good case to use [lead and lag window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) - this query filters all records with count = 1 and then get previous and next row to see if it closer than 10 minutes:

```
with cte as (
  select
      "id", "timestamp", "count",
      lag("timestamp") over(w) + '10 minutes'::interval as "lag_timestamp",
      lead("timestamp") over(w) - '10 minutes'::interval as "lead_timestamp"
  from gm_inductionloopdata as curr
  where curr."count" <> 0
  window w as (order by "timestamp")
)
select "id", "timestamp"
from cte
where
    "count" = 1 and
    ("lag_timestamp" is null or "lag_timestamp" < "timestamp") and
    ("lead_timestamp" is null or "lead_timestamp" > "timestamp")
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/15a17)

Or you can try this, and ensure that you have index on `timestamp` column of your table:

```
select *
from gm_inductionloopdata as curr
where
    curr."count" = 1 and
    not exists (
        select *
        from gm_inductionloopdata as g
        where 
           -- you can change this to between, I've used this just for readability
           g."timestamp" <= curr."timestamp" + '10 minutes'::interval and
           g."timestamp" >= curr."timestamp" - '10 minutes'::interval and
           g."id" <> curr."id" and
           g."count" = 1
    );
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/15a17/12)

BTW, please don't call your columns `"count"`, `"timestamp"` or other keywords, function names and type names.

Comment: Your first example is a nice use of lead and lag, but does not solve the problem. As the problem states, it can't have rows near 10 minutes with count<>0, it doesn't mean the rows is near by one row (as lead and lag assumes).

Comment: @MatheusOl My first query filters all rows with count = 1 and then check if closest one is farther than 10 minutes, so it should do the trick

Comment: yeah, but it will not work if there is a row farther than 10 minutes and also farther from 2 or more rows, as the case of 08:29 (from question's example), the lead of it is 08:31, but 08:35 is also within 10 minutes and you are not considering this one.

Comment: @MatheusOl have you check the SQL fiddle? There's 2 cte, I get lag and lead from ALREADY FILTERED list

Comment: ok, I got the "already filtered" now... But there is still a small problem, if the nearby count is not **exactly** 1. But it is easy to solve: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cea93/1/0 (notice I changed the line of 08:35).

Comment: nice, +1. You don't need 2 CTE's , You can just stick `"count" <> 0` into the second one.